# Issue using font on Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, fonts

I have a problem using custom font in Android Studio.
I've already read the official documentation and more then one question here, but I can not figure out how to manage the problem. So I've basically 2 problem:

1. my font file it's read like an xml and it's not showed a preview like it's read on the documentation: [this is what I see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FgIUn.png)
2. like the documentation say,

> Right-click the font folder and go to New > Font resource file. The New Resource File window appears.

but this is what I see when I do the quote:

[image]

Comment: Which issue you faced for font used ?

Comment: 1. i can't see the file preview, android studio read the font file like an xml file look at the first image.  2. when i run the app, it's show "file need to finish with .xml" on font file

Comment: **EDIT** Working solution on @savinsharma response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
You have to make an asset folder just like the image i have shared, inside which you have to add the font folder.

Your font file will be read as it is. Don't worry about it. Just give the path for the font just like this.

Typeface tfBold = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(),
                "fonts/calibrii.ttf");][1]][1]
```

[image]

Comment: That's work for me! Thanks. So basically i need to use the "old" structure instead of the new one with the (-res--font)

Comment: Yes. Glad to help. Happy Coding.

Answer (score 0):

Hello can you tell me what is your exact issue because font files in android studio rendered like that only.do you want to change font of android studio or do you want to change font of application. and tell me what have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Android Studio v3+ in order to use

> New > Font resource file

Answer (score -1):

You will need to do some customization as below.

First create a Class as below to get the Fonts for specific Use :

```
public class FontCache {

    public static final String FONTS_ITALICS = "italics.ttf";
    public static final String FONTS_SAPPY = "sappy.ttf";

    public enum LANG {
         ITALICS, SAPPY;
    }

    private static HashMap<String, Typeface> fontCache = new HashMap<>();

    public static Typeface getTypeface(String fontName, Context context) {
        Typeface typeface = fontCache.get(fontName);

        if (typeface == null) {
            try {
                typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/" + fontName);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return null;
            }

            fontCache.put(fontName, typeface);
        }

        return typeface;
    }
}
```

get your fonts ttf file and put them in `assets\fonts\`
create folders as required in `app`

Then create a custom Text view as below.

```
public class LanguageTextView extends AppCompatTextView {

        public LanguageTextView(Context context) {
            super(context);
            applyCustomFont(context);
        }

        public LanguageTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
            super(context, attrs);
            applyCustomFont(context);
        }

        public LanguageTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
            super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
            applyCustomFont(context);
        }

        private void applyCustomFont(Context context) {
            if (FontCache.getAppLanguage(context) == FontCache.LANG.ITALIC) {
                Typeface customFont = FontCache.getTypeface(FontCache.FONTS_ITALIC, context);
                setTypeface(customFont);
            } else if (FontCache.getAppLanguage(context) == FontCache.LANG.SAPPY) {
                Typeface customFont = FontCache.getTypeface(FontCache.FONTS_SAPPY, context);
                setTypeface(customFont);
            } else {
                //Typeface customFont = Typeface.DEFAULT;
                //setTypeface(customFont);
            }
        }
}
```

You can also the fonts to select using AttributeSet attrs also, Checkout Custom views for that.